# Windows batch program NOT EXIST not functioning

Tags: windows, batch-file, not-exists

I have written a simple batch file to convert movies in a folder.  The problem is, it never stops running.  It keeps processing the next movie (which it just created).  Here is the code:

```
@echo off & setlocal
FOR /r %%# in (*.mkv) DO IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpn#_265.mkv" (Title %~nx0 Processing: %%~f#
            ffmpeg -i "%%~f#" -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -map_metadata 0 -max_muxing_queue_size 1000 "%%~dpn#_265.mkv")

PAUSE
```

The file to convert is c:\tmp\c.mkv.
The code creates the first file c:\tmp\c_265.mkv, then creates a second file from that one called c:\tmp\c_265_265.mkv, and so on.

Comment: I can't delete the original as you have linked it as a duplicate.

Comment: It work for me, it stops me. However, there is a logical mistake. If it is run several times it continues to convert already converted files.

Comment: @einstein1969 - That is what I am trying to figure out.  With a file already named c:\tmp\c_265.mkv, it should not create c:\tmp\c_265_265.mkv.

Comment: ok, let me help you here. you're trying to convert files `*.mkv` when it finds a file `file_265.mkv` guess what it will do? There was a reason I mentioned in the previous question comments that you should debug and look at what is happening.

Comment: change your for loop to this. `for /f "delims=" %%# in ('dir /b /s /a-d "*.mkv" ^| findstr /v "_265.mkv"') do (`

Comment: The `FOR %%# in (set)` command, with and without `/R` switch, incorrectly process files that have been just crated by commands placed in the FOR-body itself. You can't fix such a problem inserting an `IF`. You should use `FOR /F %%# in ('dir /S /B *.mkv') DO ...` instead that _first_ run DIR on existing files, and _then_ process the generated list

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue with your code is likely to be that you're checking for the existence of every mkv file in the same directory, but with `_265` appended to the basename. So in your example `%%#` would resolve to `c:\tmp\c_265.mkv` and you'd be checking for the existence of `c:\tmp\c_265_265.mkv`, which probably isn't the only check you needed to make. You probably wanted to check to ensure that the last four characters of `%%#` were not already `_265` too.

Without changing your `for /r` methodology, *(I'd go with a `for /f` with `findstr` idea similar to [Gerhard's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244784/windows-batch-program-not-exist-not-functioning?noredirect=1#comment118861264_67244784))*, you could do it like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /R "." %%G In (
    "*.mkv"
) Do If /I "%%~xG" == ".mkv" If Not Exist "%%~dpnG_265%%~xG" (
    Set "FileBaseName=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If Not "!FileBaseName:~-4!" == "_265" (
        "ffmpeg.exe" -i "%%G" -c:v libx265 -vtag hvc1 -map_metadata 0 -max_muxing_queue_size 1000 "%%~dpnG_265%%~xG"
    )
    EndLocal
)
Pause
```

Comment: `echo %%~nG|findstr /e "_265" >nul || ffmpeg.exe ....` - no need for delayed expansion.

Comment: It would be an option @Stephan, but for me, not as good as the `for /f` method I mentioned in my answer body, and now used in Aacini's comment too. If I was going to use `findstr.exe`, I'd use it within the parentheses, not afterwards. I just felt that this way would be a more slightly better learning experience for the OP, without changing their structure/methodology.

Comment: This was the fix!  Thank you so much!